# Unable to push to secondary remote

Tags: git

I have the following remotes in git:

```
origin  file:///some_path/project/ (fetch)
origin  file:///some_path/project/ (push)
release file:///some_other_path/project/ (fetch)
release file:///some_other_path/project/ (push)
```

and I have called:

```
git push --set-upstream origin --all
git remote update
```

when I push to `origin`:

`git push origin`

everything works well, but when I try to push to `release`:

`git push release`

I get the following error:

```
fatal: You are pushing to remote 'release', which is not the upstream of
your current branch 'master', without telling me what to push
to update which remote branch.
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `master` branch has an indicator, that it's remote is `origin/master`. You can see this via `git config -l`:

```
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

This way, `git push` knows, to which remote branch it should push your changes without the need to specify it explicitly.

Try specifying the remote branch upon push to `release`: `git push release master`.

Comment: You are right. Hmm, so I take that there is no way to pre-specify a default push branch per remote?

Comment: There is a way to specify the default remote reference for a branch. You already did this via `--set-upstream origin --all`. However as @sleske suggested, there is also a `push.default` configuration parameter, which specifies the default branch to push for all remote repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `git push` which branch you want to push, and where it should go.

There is two ways to accomplish this:

- *Explicitly*: You can explicitly tell `git push` what to do by using the full syntax `git push <repository> <refspec>`. "refspec" is usually of the form `<local branch>:<remote branch>`. So in your case `git push release master:master` would push your local master to the master branch of "release".
- *Implicitly*: If you always want to push the current branch to a branch of the same name in the remote repository, you can tell git. To do this, set the pref "push.default=current" (`git config --local push.default current`). Then `git push release` will work, and will push local master to remote master.

As to why it does not work in your case: It looks like you set "push.default=simple" (or "upstream") in your configuration. Then git will expect you to push to a branch's upstream, and complain otherwise.